# Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso C#

Tags: c#

//English
Im newbie coding... i want to edit some text files in this path D:.
The problem is if one text file has been used my app throw error saying "Access Denied"...
I want to skip that error and continue with the next file... help me please...

Suppose the file United3.txt throw access denied and i cant edit.

//Español
Soy nuevo programador y quiero editar varios archivos de texto en un disco duro D.
El problema es que si uno esta siendo usado me dice acceso denegado por ende quiero omitir la edicion a el y que siga con el proximo archivo.
Este es mi método.

```
    public void startAction3()
    {
        string DiscoDuroD = "D:\\";
        if (Directory.Exists(DiscoDuroD))
        {
            string text = "Hello My Friend";
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(DiscoDuroD, 
            "United3.txt"), true))
            {
              outputFile.WriteLine(text);
            }

            string text2 = "EYY";
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(DiscoDuroD, 
            "United4.txt"), true))
            {
              outputFile.WriteLine(text);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ruta innexistente.", "Disco Duro D no detectado", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Programming questions may be asked and answered in Spanish at [es.so].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Hola GBY)

You should capture Exception and proceed with the next file.
Find below an example.

More info about try-catch structure  --> https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

De nada!

```
public void startAction3()
{
    string DiscoDuroD = "D:\\";
    if (Directory.Exists(DiscoDuroD))
    {
        string text = "Hello My Friend";
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(DiscoDuroD, 
            "United3.txt"), true))
            {
              outputFile.WriteLine(text);
            }
         }
         catch (IOException ex)
         {
             // do something in case any error occurs, leave a trace or write a console warning...
             console.WriteLine("Error fichero United3: "+ ex.Message)
         }

        string text2 = "EYY";
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(DiscoDuroD, 
        "United4.txt"), true))
        {
          outputFile.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ruta innexistente.", "Disco Duro D no detectado", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

*Perdon por la falta de puntuacion y cualquier error de espanol. Hace un tiempo sin usar espanol con regularidad.*

Sorry for the lack of punctuation and mistakes in my Spanish. It's been a while since I used Spanish regularly.

*Si tu programa tiene que procesar varios archivos en una manera igual, podrias implementar un metodo asi con 'try-catch' igual que el respuesta de David:*

If your application has to process several files in a similar way, you could implement a method like this with a 'try-catch' block similar to David's answer:

```
public void OutputToFile(string discPrefix, string fileName, string text) 
{
    if (Directory.Exists(discPrefix))
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(discPrefix, 
            fileName), true))
            {
              outputFile.WriteLine(text);
            }
         }
         catch (IOException ex)
         {
             // do something in case any error occurs, leave a trace or write a console warning...
             console.WriteLine("Error fichero" + fileName + ": " + ex.Message)
         }
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ruta innexistente.", "Disco no detectado", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

*...y usarlo entre `StartAction3` asi:*

...and call it from within your `StartAction3` like this:

```
OutputToFile("D://", "United3.txt", "Hello my friend");
OutputToFile("D://", "United4.txt", "EYY");
```

Comment: Sorry about that - I was unaware of that rule. I've added English translations.